# How disable "vue/custom-event-name-casing" errors in VSCode vetur Vue project?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, vetur

I would like to get rid of  "vue/custom-event-name-casing" warning and errors on my VSCode vetur project.

I alread created a `.eslintrc.json` file on the project root with the following content:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "vue/custom-event-name-casing": false
    }
}
```

And set the following config on `config.json`:

```
{
    "vetur.validation.template": true
}
```

but i'm still getting errors like:

```
[vue/custom-event-name-casing]
Custom event name 'editGiftPrice' must be kebab-case.eslint-plugin-vue
```

How can I desable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.eslintrc.json` can you try set value to `"off"` instead of `false`

```
{
    "rules": {
        "vue/custom-event-name-casing": "off"
    }
}
```

Comment: please write some description of your answer